# Error while compiling linux kernel on Linux mint 17

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-mint

I have the following error while trying to compile kernel Linux on Linux mint  cinnamon 64bit

```
linux-3.17.1 # make modules_install

INSTALL arch/x86/crypto/aes-x86_64.ko

Can't read private key

make[1]: *** [arch/x86/crypto/aes-x86_64.ko] Error 2

make: *** [_modinst_] Error 2
```

This command (#make modules) had been done successfully without any errors.
gcc, build-essentials and g++ are installed.

The system is running on virtual machine 4 cores + 3 GB of ram + 40GB freespace.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the problem those days when I tried to compile kernel 3.17.6 on Ubuntu 14.04. I finally found this error is simply because that the `make` process didn't finished correctly. Just like the error described, `Can't read private key.` The private key is generated when compiling the kernel at some steps. The message looks like:

```
###
### Now generating an X.509 key pair to be used for signing modules.
###
### If this takes a long time, you might wish to run rngd in the
### background to keep the supply of entropy topped up.  It
### needs to be run as root, and uses a hardware random
### number generator if one is available.
###
openssl req -new -nodes -utf8 -"sha512" -days 36500 \
        -batch -x509 -config x509.genkey \
        -outform DER -out signing_key.x509 \
        -keyout signing_key.priv 2>&1
Generating a 4096 bit RSA private key
..................................................................................++
............++
writing new private key to 'signing_key.priv'
-----
###
### Key pair generated.
###
```

The reason I didn't realized that the `make` failed is that I use `make -j 16` to let 16 process compiling simultaneously and the error was overwritten. I failed because I use Ubuntu server without bc installed.

I hope this information would help you.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this error I ran make, to compile the kernel first. I was trying make modules_install without compiling kernel first. Thus I ran the following.

> make

Comment: You can also use make -B to force compile even the packages that have been already compiled. Sometimes make fails in between, and when make is rerun, make sees some packages as already compiled, although they weren't.